# Partitioning a list based on values in tuples - Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

What is the best way to go about partitioning a list of tuples in python?

Currently I have a sorted list of tuples, by the second element (a value), and I want to find all values that are repeated at the beginning in an efficient manner.

say:

```
[ ("tearing", 3), ("me", 3), ("apart", 3), ("lisa", 3), 
  ("denny", 0), ("mark",0) ]
```

Running it through the function would return

```
[("tearing", 3), ("me", 3), ("apart", 3), ("lisa", 3)].
```

But I am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: I did not know that movie, and I'd like to express my deepest thanks for encoding a reference into these tuples. I cannot remember having laughed so heartily, and I'm not even exaggerating. SO really has it's uses...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import itertools
import operator

L = [("tearing", 3), ("me", 3), ("apart", 3), ("lisa", 3), ("denny", 0), ("mark",0)]

print list(itertools.groupby(L, operator.itemgetter(1)).next()[1])

# [('tearing', 3), ('me', 3), ('apart', 3), ('lisa', 3)]
```

But really, there was no need to remind me about that movie.

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry if I ruined your life by bringing that move back up. Do you have any suggested reading besides the pythondocs for more advanced methods related to this?

Comment: Hrm. Not really. All this stuff I picked up either by reading the docs or by consulting people more experienced than I.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import takewhile

L = [("tearing", 3), ("me", 3), ("apart", 3), ("lisa", 3), ("denny", 0), ("mark",0)]
first = L[0][1]

print list(takewhile(lambda x : x[1] == first, L))
```

a little variant of ignacio's

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' answer, using list comprehensions:

```
>>> data=[ ("tearing", 3), ("me", 3), ("apart", 3), ("lisa", 3), ("denny", 0), ("mark",0) ]
>>> print [x for x in data if x[-1]== data[0][-1]]
[('tearing', 3), ('me', 3), ('apart', 3), ('lisa', 3)]
```